# Results out of specified datetime range

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle query as follow

```
Select  "customer_name", "partner_name", "process_id", "process_time"
from "ptrans"
where to_char("process_time",'MM/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss TZH') 
      >='02/01/16 00:00:00'
  and to_char("process_time",'MM/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss TZH') 
       <='02/29/16 23:59:59' and "partner_name"='TEST';
```

and the field settings for `process_time` is                               `TIMESTAMP(3) WITH TIME ZONE`
 and sample of data in it is 18-NOV-16 12.22.19.412 AM -05:00

The issue is that when I execute the following query I get data out of the data say for e.g. 26-JUN-12 07.38.22.000 AM -04:00 which is not part of the query range? What do I need to change in the query ?

Comment: Why are you comparing strings in your `WHERE` clause rather than comparing timestamps?  String comparisons will use string comparison semantics where '03/01/15' is later than '02/01/27' because '3' is alphabetically later than '2'.

Comment: so what best should I change it  to?

Comment: why is it downvoted isnt this a valid question with what i have done and sgown?

Comment: if you want to continue to compare strings for whatever reason, compare as yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss (as that will sort in chronological and alphabetical order), but you'll have to convert ALL timestamps to a unified timezone first, otherwise 1990-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00 will improperly sort as less than (before) 1990-01-01 00:00:01 +11:00.

Comment: Why is this downvoted so badly when its already given an answer so this is a valid question?

Comment: why is this down voted when some one have given a valid answer meaning its a valid question with proper requirement being set? Can the community please look into it?

Comment: @user5313398 - I personally downvoted the question because the mistake made was not an issue figuring out the database language, but rather a basal  misunderstanding of general data types (i.e strings aka character arrays would always sort the way they did in whatever programming language you used). Strings are "always" sorted and compared on a strictly character-by-character basis and not via a "natural" sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to compare strings, you'll get string comparison semantics.  That means that you are asking whether one string is alphabetically before or after another.  Since the string '03/01/2001' comes alphabetically after '02/01/2016', that is going to result in a bunch of issues.  Presumably, you want to use date or timestamp comparison semantics so that dates in 2016 are later than dates in 2001.

I would guess that you'd want

```
where "process_time" >= date '2016-02-01'
  and "process_time" <  date '2016-03-01'
  and "partner_name"='TEST';
```

You could use an explicit `to_date` or a `to_timestamp` rather than date literals (or timestamp literals) if you would prefer.  In your original query, your literals do not have a timestamp.  If your `process_time` is potentially in a different time zone than your database server, comparing against dates may not be what you want.  You may well need to use an explicit `to_timestamp` that includes the time zone that you want the date range to be in.

If you want to use an explicit `to_timestamp` so that you are comparing against values including a time zone

```
where "process_time" >= to_timestamp( '2016-02-01 00:00:00 -05:00',
                                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM' )
  and "process_time" <  to_timestamp( '2016-03-01 00:00:00 -05:00',
                                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM' )
  and "partner_name"='TEST';
```

Comment: I dont get if I need to use to_date or to_timestamp? Which one you suggest?

Comment: @user5313398 - It depends on the requirements you didn't specify.  In my answer, I'm not using either because I prefer date and timestamp literals.  If you prefer explicit casts, you can use either `to_date` or `to_timestamp`.  Since a timestamp can have a time zone, using `to_timestamp` would allow you to specify a time zone in your predicate.  I don't know if you need to include a timestamp, it depends on your data and requirements.

Comment: so if I need timestamp since my data is stored in this format 18-NOV-16 12.22.19.412 AM -05:00? so how execute with to_timestamp?

Comment: @user5313398 - If your data is stored in a `timestamp` column, it has no format (at least not a format that is human readable).  If you want to use timestamps in your comparisons, you could do `"process_time" >= to_timestamp( '2016-02-01 00:00:00 -05:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss tzh:tzm')`

Comment: what is this tzh:tzm? so in this case I just remove the to_char

Comment: @user5313398 - `tzh` is the time zone hour and `tzm` is the time zone minute.  That converts the string "-05:00" into a time zone that is 5 hours before GMT.  You need to do more than just remove the `to_char`.  You need to change the query.  I've shown you a couple of different ways to do that depending on your requirements.

Comment: Ok I will try your method and see how it goes?

Comment: if I dont want to fix the the timezone but to pick based on the data inside?

Comment: @user5313398 - Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.  What do you mean by "pick based on the data inside"?

Comment: what I mean is that my data has like this 18-NOV-16 12.22.19.412 AM -05:00 or at time is like this 18-NOV-16 12.22.19.412 AM -07:00? Is it possiblit for me to use the timezone in the data when I do this to_timestamp( '2016-02-01 00:00:00 -05:00',
                                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM' ) so in this case it automatically pick from the data?

Comment: @JustinCave, should you not better use `to_timestamp_TZ()` when you provide time zone information? I get even an error with `to_timestamp()`